# Как сделать яндекс-карту ч/б, но геометку оставить цветной?

Tags: javascript, css3, yandex-maps-api

Ниже привел пример кода, пробую на старых картах яндекса, выбирать по этому селектору: `.ymaps-layers-pane` - работает, но в 2.1 уже нет.
Желательно сделать это кроссбраузерно, в ИЕ не работает

```css
div#map {
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
  /* Firefox 3.5+ */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: url(desaturate.svg#greyscale);
  filter: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://a159152.mcdir.ru//sites/all/themes/COSMO/2.1.js"></script>
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 700px"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  ymaps.ready(init);
  var myMap;

  function init() {
    myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
      center: [51.767481084662506, 55.113224784597655],
      zoom: 16
    });

    var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([51.767481084662506, 55.113224784597655], {}, {
      iconLayout: 'default#image',
      iconImageHref: 'http://a159152.mcdir.ru//sites/all/themes/COSMO/images/icon_location_2.png',
      iconImageSize: [158, 176],
      iconImageOffset: [-69, -277]
    });
    myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[class*="ymaps-2"][class*="-ground-pane"] {
    filter: ...
}
```

Comment: старайся писать более развернутые ответы